# PHP setcookie is not working

Tags: php

I know there are quite a few threads out there that deals with this question but every question seems unique (or so...)
I'm having trouble setting a cookie so that I can validate the user against it later
A php newbie....what might be the problem here?
I've checked the php.ini file and cookies are allowed.

```
<?php
$capt_error = "";
$already_made_post = "";
$mismatch = "";
$name = $message = "";
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    session_start();
    if (empty($_POST["capt"])) {
        $capt_error = "Fältet är obligatoriskt.";
    } else {
        // validate captcha
        if($_POST['capt'] != $_SESSION['rand']) {
            $name = $_POST["name"];
            $message = $_POST['message'];
            $mismatch = "Inmatningen av CAPTHA är fel. Vänligen prova igen.";
        }
        else {
            $ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
            $time_stamp = date('Y-m-d H:i');
            $cookie_name = $_POST['name'];
            $cookie_value = $ip_address;

            // write to file but only if cookie is not set
            if(isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_value]) && $_COOKIE[$cookie_value] == $cookie_value) {
                $already_made_post = "Du har redan ett inlägg i gästboken!";
            }
            else {
                $data = "\n" . $_POST['name'] . ',' . $_POST['message'] . ',' . $ip_address . ',' . $time_stamp;
                $ret = file_put_contents('data.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
                if ($ret == false) {
                    die('Fel vid skrivning till fil. Skrivrättigheter saknas');
                }

                // set cookie
                setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value); // IS NOT SET
                if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
                    echo "Cookie named '" . $cookie_name . "' is not set!";
                } else {
                    echo "Cookie '" . $cookie_name . "' is set!<br>";
                    echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
?>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="labb1.css" type="text/css">

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Labb 1</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 class="title">Laboration 1 - Gästboken</h1>
        <table border="1">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="3" class="table-title">Min Gästbok</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="bold">FRÅN</td>
                    <td class="bold">INLÄGG</td>
                    <td class="bold">LOGGNING</td>
                </tr>
                <?php
                    // open file
                    $f = fopen("data.txt", "r");
                    // while not end of file
                    while (!feof($f)) {
                        // split values with -
                        $arr = explode(",", trim(fgets($f), "\r\n"));
                        print "<tr>";
                            print "<td>$arr[0]</td>";
                            print "<td>$arr[1]</td>";
                            print "<td>IP: $arr[2]<br>TID: $arr[3]</td>";
                        print "</tr>";
                    }
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <form action="" method="post">
            <div class="border">
                <div>
                    <span>Namn:</span>
                    <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span>Meddelande:</span>
                    <textarea name="message" rows="5"><?php echo $message;?></textarea>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <?php
                        $rand = substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat("0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", 5)), 0, 5);
                        session_start();
                        $_SESSION["rand"] = $rand;
                        print "<span>CAPTCHA skriv detta i rutan nedan: </span> <span class='red bold'>$rand</span>"
                    ?>
                    <span class="error">* <?php echo $capt_error; ?></span>
                    <input type="text" name="capt">
                    <span class="error"><?php echo $mismatch?></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Skicka">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span class="red">*</span> är ett obligatoriskt fält
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span class="error"><?php echo $already_made_post?></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you able to set cookie without any condition? Do you know how to check out cookies in your browser?

Comment: What do you mean by "able to set cookie without any condition"? I don't quite follow you :) The cookies created looks like this: Array ( [mona] => ::1 [PHPSESSID] => 2kbh59m9rm008epvlv73qhdfh6 [sam] => ::1 [sammy] => ::1 )

Comment: You need to serparate two things: my cookies does not work and my condition is wrong

Comment: Thanks for you reply. But how do I set a cookie?

Comment: You have not set the expiration time in **set_cookies()** function, and so your cookies are not setting properly

Comment: But I thought the expiration time is optional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`session_start();` should be at the top of the page for the sessions to work. In your code above it only gets called when the user submits the form. Move it to line 2.

Answer (score 0):

You have not set the expire perameter:

**Set your cookies like this**

```
$expire=time()+60*60*24*30; 
setcookie ("name","value", $expire,"/");
```

**$expire** variable holds the value time when our cookies should expire,

Answer (score 0):

I read your code and now I see this

```
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value); // IS NOT SET
if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
```

From [common pitfalls](http://php.net/set_cookie#refsect1-function.setcookie-notes)

> Cookies will not become visible until the next loading of a page that
>   the cookie should be visible for.